# Improve SQL query by replacing inner query

Tags: sql, join, select, inner-query

I'm trying to simplify this SQL query (I replaced real table names with metaphorical), primarily get rid of the inner query, but I'm brain frozen can't think of any way to do it.

My major concern (aside from aesthetics) is performance under heavy loads

The purpose of the query is to count all books grouping by genre found on any particular shelve where the book is kept (hence the inner query which is effectively telling which shelve to count books on).

```
SELECT g.name, count(s.book_id) occurances FROM genre g
LEFT JOIN shelve s ON g.shelve_id=s.id
WHERE s.id=(SELECT genre_id FROM book WHERE id=111)
GROUP BY s.genre_id, g.name
```

Comment: Your query should be fine, although `s.genre_id` is not needed in the `GROUP BY`.  I am also lost on how `s.id = b.genre_id`.  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to know many books that are on a shelf are in the same genre as book 111: if you liked book "X", we have this many similar books in stock.

One thing I noticed is the `WHERE` clause in the original required a value for the `shelve` table, effectively converting it to an INNER JOIN. And speaking of JOINs, you can JOIN instead of the nested select.

```
SELECT g.name, count(s.book_id) occurances 
FROM genre g
INNER JOIN shelve s ON s.id = b.shelve_id
INNER JOIN book b on b.genre_id = s.id 
WHERE b.id=111
GROUP BY g.id, g.name
```

Thinking about it more, I might also start with `book` rather than `genre`. In the end, the only reason you need the `genre` table at all is to find the `name`, and therefore matching to it by `id` may be more effective.

```
SELECT g.name, count(s.book_id) occurances 
FROM book b 
INNER JOIN shelve s ON s.id = b.genre_id
INNER JOIN genre g on g.shelve_id = s.id
WHERE b.id=111
GROUP BY g.id, g.name
```

Not sure they meet your idea of "simpler" or not, but they are alternatives.

... unless matching `shelve.id` with `book.genre_id` is a typo in the question. It seems very odd the two tables would share the same `id` values, in which case these will both be wrong.

Comment: It does seem from the question that a genre exists on one shelf, but a shelf can hold multiple genres. They must have very big shelves...